# PHP/MySQL - Performance considerations querying (select only) 48k rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently attempting to build a web application that relies quite heavily on postcode data (supplied from [OS CodePoint Open](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html)). The postcode database has 120 tables which breaks down the initial postcode prefix (i.e. SE, WS, B). Inside these tables there are between 11k - 48k rows with 3 fields (Postcode, Lat, Lng).

What I need to be able to do is for a user to come online, enter their postcode i.e. SE1 1LD which then selects the SE table, and converts the postcode into a lat / lng.

I am fine with doing this on a PHP level. My concern is.. well the huge number of rows that will be queried and whether it is going to grind my website to a halt?

If there are any techniques that I should know about, please do let me know.. I've never worked with tables with big numbers in!

Thanks :)

Comment: So, you mean that there is a `SE` table, a `WS` one, a `B` one, etc, all with same structure `(Postcode, Lat, Lng)` ? Haven't they heard of normalization?

Comment: I assume they did it to keep the file sizes down. Would querying 1.7 million rows cause an issue?

Comment: Querying tables with million of rows can be really fast with proper indexes. If a query returns a few rows, and there are indexes that can be used, it doesn't have to search the whole table, it uses the index(es). And then retrieves the few rows from the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct, there is a `SE` table, a `WS` one, a `B` one, etc. In all, **120 tables with same structure** `(Postcode, Lat, Lng)`.

I strongly propose you **normalize** the tables.

You can have either one table:

```
postcode( prefix, postcode, lat, lng)
```

or two:

```
postcode( prefixid , postcode, lat, lng )

prefix( prefixid, prefix )
```

The postcode table will be slighly bigger than 11K-48K rows, about 30K x 120 = 3.6M rows but it will save you time for writing different queries for every prefix and quite complex ones if, for example, you want to search for latitude and longitude (imagine a query that searches in 120 tables).

If you are not convinced try to add a `person` table so you can add data for your users. How this table will be related to the postcode table(s) ?

---

EDIT

Since the `prefix` is just the first characters of the `postcode` which is also the `primary key`, there is no need for extra field or second table. I would simply combine the 120 tables into one:

```
postcode( postcode, lat, lng )
```

Then queries like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM postode
WHERE postcode = 'SE11LD'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM postode
WHERE postcode LIKE 'SE%'
```

will be fast, as they will be using the primary key index.

Comment: The prefix isn't an issue as such, and is only used to find the correct table to query ie `NE1 2GB` would use `NE` to select the `NE` table and then query `NE12GB` to select its `lat` and `lng` values. Is querying 3mil rows going to cause a slowdown vs querying seperate tables?

Comment: If there is an index on field `(postcode)`, the difference will be minimal. The advantages of using one (normalized) table, huge in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

48K are not big numbers. 48 million is. :) If your tables are properly indexed (put indexes on the fields you use in the `WHERE` clause) it won't be a problem at all.

Avoid `LIKE`, and use INNER JOINS instead of LEFT JOINs if possible.

Comment: Well I never knew that! haha, thanks for that. The postcodes will be PK's so I would assume apart from that the queries shouldn't cause too  much of an issue?

Comment: run a few queries in pma or terminal and see what the time is, should not be more than a few ms

Answer (score 4):

selecting from 48k rows in mysql is not big, in fact its rather small. index it properly and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have indexes on the appropriate columns, there should be no problem. One of my customers has the postcode database stored in a table like :

```
CREATE TABLE `postcode_geodata` (
`postcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`x_coord` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`y_coord` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
UNIQUE KEY `postcode_idx` (`postcode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

And we have no problems (from a performance point of view) in querying that.

If your table did become really large, then you could always look at using MySQL's partitioning support - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html - but I wouldn't look at that until you've done the easier things first (see below).

If you think performance is an issue, turn on MySQL's slow_query_log (see /etc/mysql/my.cnf) and see what it says (you may also find the command 'mysqldumpslow' useful at this point for analysing the slow query log).

Also try using the 'explain' syntax on the MySQL cli - e.g.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT a,b,c FROM table WHERE d = 'foo' and e = 'bar'
```

These steps will help you optimise the database - by identifying which indexes are (or aren't) being used for a query.

Finally, there's the mysqltuner.pl script (see http://mysqltuner.pl) which helps you optmise the MySQL server's settings (e.g. query cache, memory usage etc which will affect I/O and therefore performance/speed).